# Maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

While trying to find a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, I ran into something that seems contradictory.

If we let $J = \{(a,a):a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ then $J \cong \mathbb{Z}$ given the by isomorphism $(a,a) \mapsto a$.

Then (at least it seems to me):
$$J/(7,7)J \cong \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$$

This is a field, which implies $(7,7)J = \{(7a,7a):a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a maximal ideal.

But $(7,7)J \subsetneq \{(7a, 7b): a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ which is a counterexample to the claim that $(7,7)J$ is maximal.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $(7,7)J$ is a maximal ideal in $J$, not in the whole of $\Bbb Z^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have written *is* correct: $J/(7,7)J$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$ but what I think you're doing is you're confusing $J/(7,7)J$ with $\Bbb Z^2/(7,7) J$. $(7,7)J$ is maximal **in** $J$. It is not maximal in $\Bbb Z^2$ as you have demonstrated.

Comment: Of, of course :) thanks

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest thinking about it like this: $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is generated by $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. When you mod out by $(7,7)$, you are essentially giving $(1,1)$ an order of $7$. Hence, you get $\Bbb Z\times(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Can you clarify why $(1,1)$ has an order of $7$ in $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$(or I have misunderstood). Wait nvm: You have written $(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z) /7\Bbb Z$ I presume

Comment: @SkiesBurn: This follows since $7\cdot(1,1)=(7,7)\in J$, and in $\Bbb Z^2/J$, any elements in $J$ get sent to $0$.